# Discord py, the bot sends a message twice

Tags: python, discord.py

I am totally new to StackOverflow, and also quite new to python. I've been coding a bot for a few days, and it worked fine until this evening. I tried to add a leveling system (which I found here, can't remember where though). It does work, but now my bot sends a message in the chat twice, on every command.

This is my relevant code:

```
import discord
import datetime
import requests
import random
import json
import time
import asyncio
import discord.ext.commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord import Game
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

intents = Intents.all()
BOT_PREFIX = ("z!", "Z!", "zticko!")
TOKEN = 'REDACTED'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    activity = discord.Activity(name='Dennis... ;)', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(#the channel ID)
    if 'among us' in message.content or 'Among us' in message.content:
        await channel.send("Glöm bara inte votea ut <@!userid> första rundan, I promise - han är Impostor 8/10 gånger.")
        emoji = client.get_emoji(robinemo)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await client.process_commands(message)
    #####################################################################
    #                                                                   #
    #               LEVELSYSTEMET BÖRJAR NEDAN                          #
    #                                                                   #
    #####################################################################
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1
    print("Uppdaterar en User")

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp
    pass

async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} har levlat upp till level {lvl_end}! Gz till ding!')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
    pass



#
# Vid ny användare, lägg in för LEVELSYSTEMET
#

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    
    print("Ny user!")


@client.command(description="Kolla vilken level du ligger på.", brief="Vilken level är du?")
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'Du är på level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} är på level {lvl}!')
    pass
```

The output would look something like:

BOT
Today 04:17
@User är på level 2!
@User är på level 2!

And it's only supposed to send one of those. It also runs every other command I have twice. It did not do this, until I added the leveling system. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm sorry if this is a rookie mistake, I'm trying to learn and balance my medical studies at the same time, haha...

Comment: OH WOW, I'm sorry guys. I had the line "await client.process_commands(message)" twice in the on_message event. I removed one, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

OH WOW, I'm sorry guys. I had the line "await client.process_commands(message)" twice in the on_message event. I removed one, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

well you need to do:

```py
@client.command()
async def command(ctx): #u can change the comand if you want
    await ctx.send("enter message here")
    await ctx.send("enter same message here")
```